# Race condition with multiple updates PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table called `cards`, Each user can create/have multiple cards. One of the cards must be set as default.
Sometimes when a user performs multiple requests to set another card as default at the same time, In the end, There are two or more default cards.

**Initial table:**

| id | user_id | is_default |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 0 |
| 2 | 50 | 1 |

**Requests (performed at the same time):**
`PATCH http://localhost:8000/cards/1/default`
`PATCH http://localhost:8000/cards/2/default`

**Result:**
Both of them are set as default.

| id | user_id | is_default |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 1 |
| 2 | 50 | 1 |

**Code:**

```php
use App\Models\Card;

public function setAsDefault(Request $request, $id)
{
  Card::where('user_id', $request->user()->id)->update(['is_default' => false]);
  Card::where([
    'id' => $id,
    'user_id' => $request->user()->id
  ])->update(['is_default' => true]);

  return ['status' => true'];
}
```

**Possible solutions:**

1. [Transaction with shared lock](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#pessimistic-locking)
2. [Rate Limiting](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/rate-limiting)

**Are there other simpler solutions?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using transactions. Something like this...

```php
   
     DB::transaction(function() use ($request, $id) {
       Card::where('user_id', $request->user()->id)
             ->update(['is_default' => false]);
 
       Card::where([
           'id' => $id,
           'user_id' => $request->user()->id
         ])->update(['is_default' => true]);

                    
     });
```

Almost all high load apps need transactions mechanisms to make "database change" atomic.

Comment: Well, the same happens in a transaction without a `sharedLock` or `lockForUpdate` on the `user`.

Comment: Try temporary replace two queries with one plain sql query

"update ... set ... where ... ; update ... set .. .where ..."

And if same problem will happens again, try logging queries. may be there are something in argumens...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the code for updates.

In first set `is_default = 1` for default card.

In second set `is_default = 0` for others card exclude default card.

Don't know how to make this is your "framework" but in SQL it should by two query
For example, set card with id 1 as default

```
UPDATE cards SET is_default = 1 WHERE user_id = 50 AND id = 1;
UPDATE cards SET is_default = 0 WHERE user_id = 50 AND id <> 1;
```

Comment: I've already tried this method. The result is None are set as default because of Race condition.